# Monte Carlo simulation from a pdf using runif

Tags: r, montecarlo

I'm given a pdf for X where f(x) = 2x when x is between 0 and 1, and f(x) = 0 otherwise. In class we learned to sample from a uniform distribution and transform the data to solve for y, however, I'm unsure how to apply that here because if I generate data from a uniform distribution then most of it will be between 0 and 1.

Am I doing these steps in the wrong order? It just seems weird to have a PDF that will lead to most of the data just being multiplied by 2.

Comment: It seems that you learned about the [inverse sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) in your class. This algorithm requires the inverse CDF, not the inverse PDF.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how to do this. One way could be with rejection sampling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling. Simply put:

1. Sample a point on the x-axis from the proposal distribution.
2. Draw a vertical line at this x-position, up to the curve of the proposal distribution.
3. Sample uniformly along this line from 0 to the maximum of the probability density function. If the sampled value is greater than the value of the desired distribution at this vertical line, return to step 1.

   ```
   n=1e5  
   x=runif(n)  
   t=runif(n)  
   hist(x[ifelse(2*t<2*x,T,F)])
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I will use R's convention of naming PDF's with an initial `d` and CDF's with an initial `p`.
It is very simple. Compute the antiderivative of `dmydist(x) = 2*x` to get `pmydist = sqrt(x)`. The associate RNG is immediate.

```
dmydist <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x >= 0 & x <= 1, 2*x, 0)
}
pmydist <- function(y) {
  ifelse(x >= 0 & x <= 1, sqrt(y), 0)
}
rmydist <- function(n) pmydist(runif(n))

set.seed(1234)
x <- rmydist(10000)

hist(x, prob = TRUE)
lines(seq(0, 1, by = 0.01), dmydist(seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)))
```

[image]